# How can i allow user to save PDF on a specific location

Tags: asp.net, itext

I have a PDF file which saves into the download folder, but i want to allow user to select the location. Here is my code.
I am using iTextSharp for the PDF creation.
It always download the PDF into Downloads Folder, Please Help.

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 15, 12);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
document.Open();
pdfPage ab = new pdfPage();

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
table.SetWidths(new int[] { 3, 1, 2, 3 });
table.SpacingBefore = 5f;
var blackListTextFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8f, Color.BLACK);

phrase = new Phrase();
phrase.Add(new Chunk("", blackListTextFont));
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(phrase));
cell.Padding = 5f;
cell.BackgroundColor = new Color(85, 142, 213);
cell.Colspan = 4;
table.AddCell(cell);

phrase = new Phrase();
phrase.Add(new Chunk("I", blackListTextFont));
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(phrase));
cell.Padding = 5f;
cell.BackgroundColor = new Color(85, 142, 213);
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
table.AddCell(cell);

phrase = new Phrase();
phrase.Add(new Chunk("D", blackListTextFont));
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(phrase));
cell.Padding = 5f;
cell.BackgroundColor = new Color(85, 142, 213);
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
table.AddCell(cell);

phrase = new Phrase();
phrase.Add(new Chunk("O", blackListTextFont));
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(phrase));
cell.Padding = 5f;
cell.BackgroundColor = new Color(85, 142, 213);
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
table.AddCell(cell);


phrase = new Phrase();
phrase.Add(new Chunk("S", blackListTextFont));
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(phrase));
cell.Padding = 5f;
cell.BackgroundColor = new Color(85, 142, 213);
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
table.AddCell(cell);
table.CompleteRow();

document.Add(table);

document.Close();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= SampleExport.pdf");
Response.End();
Connection.Close();
```

Comment: negative !!!! Could you please tell me why??

Answer (score 1):

It is up to the browser where the default location it will save the file is, there is no way to change it server-side.

[See this article](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-download-location-ie-chrome) for information about how the default download location can be changed on a per-browser basis.

Comment: This is a Question and Answer site, not a forum. If you have another question, please open a new question.